# Creat Signature for Oauth 1.0 with Curl and PHP - Fixing error "Unsupported signature method in the header. Require HMAC-SHA256"

Tags: php, curl, oauth

What is wrong?

This is all my code, I think that it should be fine, but I don't know why... with **Postman** I haven't errors and I receive the tokens while with Curl I receive this error. I'm working in local with Mamp pro.

- The error received is:

  [image]
- My Code To generate the **Signature** and get the **Token**:

```php
$url = "https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";
 $data = array(
   "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
 );

 $oauthNonce = mt_rand();
 $oauthTimestamp = time();
 $oauthCustomereKey = "******";
 $oauthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA256";
 $httpMethod = "POST";
 $oauthVersion = "1.0";
 $keySecret = "*****";

 $baseString = $httpMethod."&". urlencode($url);
 $paramString =
       "grant_type=client_credentials&".
       "oauth_consumer_key=". urlencode($oauthCustomereKey).
       "&oauth_nonce=". urlencode($oauthNonce).
       "&oauth_signature_method=". urlencode($oauthSignatureMethod).
       "&oauth_timestamp=". urlencode($oauthTimestamp).
       "&oauth_version=". urlencode($oauthVersion)
;
 $baseString = $baseString . "&" . urlencode($paramString);
 var_dump($baseString);
 $signingKey= urlencode($keySecret) . "&";

 $signature = urlencode(
     base64_encode(
     hash_hmac(
         'sha256',
         $baseString,
         $signingKey,
         true
     )
   )
 );

   $params = [
     "oauth_consumer_key"     => $oauthCustomereKey,
     "oauth_nonce"            => $oauthNonce,
     "oauth_signature_method" => $oauthSignatureMethod,
     "oauth_timestamp"        => $oauthTimestamp,
     "oauth_version"          => $oauthVersion,
     "oauth_signature"        => $signature
 ];

 // $lol = 'oauth_consumer_key="' . $oauthCustomereKey . '",oauth_signature_method="'.$oauthSignatureMethod . '",oauth_timestamp="'.$oauthTimestamp.'",oauth_nonce="'.$oauthNonce.'",oauth_version="'.$oauthVersion.'",oauth_signature="'.$signature.'"';
 /* This will give you the proper encoded string to include in your Authorization header */
 $params = http_build_query($params, null, ',', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
 $authorization = "Authorization: OAuth " . $params;

var_dump($authorization);

 if(!$curl = curl_init()){
     exit;
 }
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   "Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   $authorization));
 $token = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $token;
```

- Result basestring (dump on line 87):

```
string(253) "POST&https%3A%2F%2Faccount.api.here.com%2Foauth2%2Ftoken&grant_type%3Dclient_credentials%26oauth_consumer_key%3D********%26oauth_nonce%3D1468397107%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1605523226%26oauth_version%3D1.0"
```

And on the doc [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication-authorization/dev_guide/topics/error-messages.html) we have this example... it look the same:

```
POST
  &https%3A%2F%2Faccount.api.here.com%2Foauth2%2Ftoken
  &grant_type=client_credentials%26oauth_consumer_key%3Daccess-key-id-1234%26oauth_nonce%3DLIIpk4%26
oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1456945283%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

Finally... after 2 days...
There are 2 errors on the code above:

1. The parameter $data to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
2. Oauth 1.0 wants the double quotes.

So change:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

With

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

This is strange for me, because with curl I use http_build_query with GET request and not POST, where we can use $data directly like array.
And delete:

```
$params = http_build_query($params, null, ',', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

And write the query with your beautifuls hand because $params doesn't have double quote.